# Trying to update json array using net minidev json but get casting error

Tags: java, json, karate

I am trying to remove or update a few fields from a jsonArray which consists of *LinkedHashMap*.  I've looked up how to update a LinkedHashMap and a *put(key,value)* is the standard process but when try that I get *java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap* error.

My code is as follow:

```
public static JSONArray updateJsonFields(JSONArray json, LinkedHashMap fieldMap) {
    JSONArray updatedJson = new JSONArray();
    int sizeJson = json.size();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeJson ; i++) {
        ((LinkedHashMap) json.get(i)).forEach((key, value) -> {
            if(key.equals("responseHeaders")) {
                ((LinkedHashMap) value).forEach((fieldKey, fieldValue ) -> {
                    if(fieldKey.equals("Date")){
                        ((LinkedHashMap) fieldValue).put("Date", fieldMap.get("Date"));
                    } else if( fieldKey.equals("TransID") ) {
                        ((LinkedHashMap) fieldValue).put("TransID", fieldMap.get("TransID"));
                    }
                });
            } else if (key.equals("requestTimeStamp")) {
                ((LinkedHashMap) value).put("requestTimeStamp", fieldMap.get("requestTimeStamp"));
            } else if (key.equals("responseTime")) {
                ((LinkedHashMap) value).remove("responseTime");
            }
        });
    }
    return updatedJson;
}
```

What also makes it confusing is that the remove method returns the same error.  I've not worked with 
LinkedHashMaps in Java till now so I am not sure what I need to do.  I've looked for about two days now and can't seem to find the answer I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some known weirdness with JSON conversion when doing it in Java, please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/787

So I strongly suggest doing your JSON manipulation in Karate directly in this case.

Updating and deleting is very easy. Here are examples:

```
* def temp = { foo: 'bar' }
* temp.foo = 'hello'
* match temp == { foo: 'hello' }
* temp.bar = 'world'
* match temp == { foo: 'hello', bar: 'world' }

# * remove temp.foo
* karate.remove('temp', '$.foo')
* match temp == { bar: 'world' }
```

Comment: Thank you. @Peter Thomas